# When I insert new fields using new method then deleting previous fields and over writing

Tags: flutter

When I insert new fields using new method  then deleting previous fields and over writing. How to add new fields without replace in previous fields ?

this is my code.

```
void displayMessage() {
    List<CheckBoxModel> checked =
        checkboxes.where((element) => element.value).toList();
    String result = '';
    checked.forEach((element) {
      result = result + element.title;
    });
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(sp.uid)
        .set({
      "firstWord": value,
      "disease": result,
    });
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ChildDetailsScreen()),
    );
    _saveDataFirstWord(value!);
  }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert new fields without deleting previous fields, don't use `set`, use `update` instead.

Like so:

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(sp.uid)
        .update({
      "firstWord": value,
      "disease": result,
    });
```